# hour must be between 1 and 12 - sql error or ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, date-arithmetic

I have a column with timestamp stored in 20-02-18 03:50:58.347000000 PM format. These timestamps are stored in multiple rows so I want to update only the milliseconds in this column by using random number generator so that it will be unique for every row. I tried to use below query for updating the time

```
UPDATE table 
   SET field = TO_TIMESTAMP('18-01-18 02:23:27.265000050 PM'|| ' ' || TO_TIMESTAMP(field, 'HH:MI:SS.FF'),'DD-MM-YY HH:MI:SS.FF')
where objid = XXX;
```

I'm getting an error - ORA-01849: hour must be between 1 and 12

if I change the query to below format - 
ow query for updating the time

```
UPDATE table 
   SET field = TO_TIMESTAMP('18-01-18 02:23:27.265000050 PM'|| ' ' || TO_TIMESTAMP(field, 'hh12:MI:SS.FF'),'DD-MM-YY hh12:MI:SS.FF')
where objid = XXX;
```

I get below error - 
ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string. Can anyone check this please

Comment: When I execute this I get an error ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string

Comment: Do you really store the timestamp values as `VARCHAR2`? If not, why do you run `TO_TIMESTAMP` on a value which is already a `TIMESTAMP`?

Comment: Why do you think random numbers will generate unique values?

Comment: What is the data type of column `field`? Is it a number of milliseconds?

Comment: Hi Wenfried, yes, it is already stored in timestamp format and I thought of using random numbers as it will give a different value for each row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't pfaff around with date masks. Just use INTERVAL to add milliseconds:

```
update t23
set ts = ts + interval '0.001' second * dbms_random.value(0,999)
```

Here is [a demo on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=e2f8366f78b2e73be01ed1c4a1a06cdc).

---

> using random number generator so that it will be unique for every row.

Not guaranteed. A random series can still contain duplicate numbers. However, if you have only a few timestamps per second it's unlikely you will get any clashes. Likelihood of collisions increases with the number of timestamps per second. So if uniqueness is the object of the exercise this is the wrong approach. You need a different key to uniquely identify your records (probably a technical key such as a sequence or identity column).

Comment: this is actually a better solution for now. Thanks for the help. Stack over flow is awesome I'm learning a new thing everytime.